# How to check file owner in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to check file owner in linux

i am trying to run this bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
uname2=$(ls -l $1 | awk '{print $3}');
if [ $uname2 == $USER ]
then echo owner
else echo no owner
fi
```

it gives error ==' unary operator expected.
what is wrong? ubuntu server 10.04.

Comment: command works at home and doesn't work at work pc. Don't know why. Works without double quotes. Very strange...

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`... Better to use `stat -c %U file.dat`...

Answer (score 21):

Use `=` not `==` for comparison. The [test(1) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) says:

```
STRING1 = STRING2
        the strings are equal
```

I'd also recommend using [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) to find out the owner instead of some `ls` hacks. Some double quotes and an extra `x` would also be nice.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
uname2="$(stat -c '%U' "$1")"  # change this if not using Linux
if [ "x${uname2}" = "x${USER}" ]; then
    echo owner
else
    echo no owner
fi
```

If you're using [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html), you can replace `stat -c` with  `stat --format` to make the script more readable.
If you're using [FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1), [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/stat.1), [OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/man1/stat.1) or [DragonFly](https://man.dragonflybsd.org/?command=stat&section=1) you need to replace it with `stat -f`.

Comment: The extra "x" is only needed in, I think, the original Bourne shell, or at least in implementations that had trouble with empty strings. It is unnecessary today; `[ "" = "$USER" ]` will work in any POSIX-compatible shell, and especially in `bash`.

Comment: under `busybox` use `stat -c '%U'`

Answer (score 13):

The `-O` *file* option tests if *file* exists and is owned by the effective user ID.

```
if [[ -O "$0" ]]; then
    echo "owner"
else
    echo "no owner"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put `"` next to variables.

```
uname2=$(ls -l $1 | awk '{print $3}');
if [ "$uname2" == "$USER" ]
then echo owner
else echo no owner
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running your script with `bash -x` and you can see exactly what's going on.  I bet that one of your variables is empty.  You can protect against this  by quoting the variables, like this:

```
if [ "$uname2" == "$USER" ]
```